# Rails Saving a Status Value, (compared using ==)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a mailer and allow a status to be changed to pending upon creation. So I have the following in my controller:

```
class Api::UserTrainingResourcesController < Api::BaseController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def create
    @user_training_resource = UserTrainingResource::Create.call(user_training_resource_params)
    respond_with(@user_training_resource)
  end


  def destroy
    @user_training_resource = UserTrainingResource.find_by(params[:id])
    @user_training_resource.destroy
  end

  private

  def user_training_resource_params
    params.require(:user_training_resources).permit(:training_resources_id, :status).merge(spud_user_id: current_user_id)
  end
end
```

Then in my Operations I have the following create:

```
class UserTrainingResource
  class Create < Operation

    def call(params)
      params[:status] = :pending
      training_resource = UserTrainingResource.new(params)
      UserTrainingResourceMailer.requested(training_resource).deliver_later if training_resource.save
      training_resource
    end

  end
end
```

My model has:

```
class UserTrainingResource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training_resource
  enum status: [:pending, :confirmed, :rejected], _prefix: :status

  scope :employee, -> { where.not(status: ['rejected']) }
  scope :hr, -> { where(status: SameScope::HR) }

  module SameScope
    HR = ['pending', 'confirmed', 'rejected'].freeze
  end

  def view_user_training_resource_request?(user)
    return true if user.human_resources && SameScope::HR.include?(status)
    false
  end

  def change_status?(user, status)
    return true if user.human_resources && SameScope::HR.include?(status)
    false
  end

end
```

Then in my test I have:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UserTrainingResource::Create do

  let(:params) { attributes_for(:user_training_resource).merge(user_id: create(:user).id) }

  describe '#call' do
    it 'queues a mailer' do
      ut = UserTrainingResource::Create.call(params)
      expect(UserTrainingResourceMailer).to send_mail(:requested)
      expect(ut.status).to eq('pending')
    end
  end

end
```

So this ends up with a Failure/Error: expect(ut.status).to eq('pending') Expect: "pending", got" nil. (compared using ==)

I thought the issue was that pending was not saving to the db but that's because I had status present as a string not an integer when using enum in the model. But it's still getting nil.

Edit:
After noticing that I had status using string I went ahead and added in a migration file to change it to integer. Test failed with the same issue. Tried to rollback my test environment, failed. Did a rake db:reset. Re-added in data in both development and test. Still getting the issue of essentially:

> Failure/Error: expect(ut.status).to eq('pending')
>
> expected: "pending"
>           got: nil
>
> (compared using ==)

Comment: So, the whole post can be simplified to "why `UserTrainingResource.new(status: :pending).status` is `nil`?", correct?

Comment: I was probably overly verbose in my attempt to explain how the test fails and it appears to be that for some reason I can't save/update status

Comment: What do you mean, "can't save/update status"?. If you do `ut.reload.pending?`, what does it return?

Comment: When I do ut.save I end up with:
  UserTrainingResource Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "user_training_resources" SET "status" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "user_training_resources"."id" = $3  [["status", 0], ["updated_at", "2018-07-23 17:26:54.315324"], ["id", 6]]
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
=> true. When I do ut.reload.pending I receive:   UserTrainingResource Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "user_training_resources".* FROM "user_training_resources" WHERE "user_training_resources"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `pending' for #<UserTrainingResource:0x00007faae98d0f18>

Comment: `pending?`, not `pending`

Comment: ut.reload.pending?
  UserTrainingResource Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "user_training_resources".* FROM "user_training_resources" WHERE "user_training_resources"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `pending?' for #<UserTrainingResource:0x00007faae98d0f18>
from /Users/jacob.moore/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activemodel-5.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'

Comment: Hm, I thought `enum` does add those helpers. Anyhow, I see that `status` is indeed persisted. `["status", 0]`.

Comment: When I call ut again the status is still set to nil

Comment: It might be that prefix option. Why did you add it? With it, looks like `ut.status_pending?` should work.

Comment: Had status as string instead of integer. Failing the test however. Stripped out prefix as it was old code.

Comment: Do active record enums support symbols? I haven't used them much, but IIRC they are string based?

Comment: @BM5k: in this case, they're mapped to an integer.